# What would be the best way to make a sort of drop-down-more-info div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs with a more-info button on the bottom of each, like so:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpVbPq

And when a user presses ' more info ' I would like for it to extend to the bottom and show extra info, obviously.

The problem is under the more-info div, text is seen, but what if I want to hide whats under it, even if its opacity is 0.6 ?

I thought it would've been the best if I draw what I need, so here:

[image]

Codepen code below:

html

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="info">
      <p>
          dummy text
      </p>
        <div class="more-info">more info</div>
      </div>
      <div class="info"><div class="more-info">more info</div></div>
      <div class="info"><div class="more-info">more info</div></div>
      <div class="info"><div class="more-info">more info</div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
.wrapper  {
  width: 1045px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.info  {
  width: 500px; height: 200px;
  background-color: #1A5AB6;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.more-info {
  width: 100%; height: 40px;
  background-color: #0C1B44;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.more-info:hover  {background-color: #010716;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the text expand, you can use a little jQuery to set the height to automatically adapt to however much text there is, and hide the 'more info' button entirely:

```
$(".more-info").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("opacity", "0");
  $(this).parent().css("height", "auto");
});
```

With regards to not having the text visible behind the 'more info' button, you would **need** to set the opacity to 1:

```
.more-info {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This naturally distorts the colour a little, but you can always change the background colour and hover colour to cover this.

I've created an updated pen showcasing this [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/NpEjOd).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I already had something like this, sadly.
Here is what i have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpVbPq (i edited the original pen).

As you can see the more-info div doesnt disappear, and display: none i put into the function doesnt work, so I cant place the less-info div in its place.

How would i go about making it so when i press more info it disappears (animated) and less info appears in its place instead?

Answer (score 0):

change your class selector definition as shown below:

```
.more-info {
    width: 100%; height: 20%;
    background-color: #0C1B44;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.6;
 }
```

Then add this css for your paragraph element:

```
p {
  height: 75%; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question: "what would be the best way to make a sort of drop-down-more-info div?"

There is a built in function in Boot Strap that allows you to use a "data" class that does all the crunching for you. Just call on their css and js files externally or host on your server. Familiarize yourself with their data classes and call on their css/js classes to simplify previously arduous coding, like revealing a hidden DIV on click!

Note the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#more_info"` lines in my div that holds the span tag that is the control for revealing the hidden `<div id="more_info">`:

```
`<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more_info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <span title="Click for more info">more info</span></div>`
```

Then note the class in my hidden div. Note the id of the hidden div and the data-target #more_info. This can be used for classes as well, ie: `.more_info`. Everything is explained in more detail at bootstrap Github or their official site: http://getbootstrap.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="info">
  <p>
      Honestly, Bootstrap would be the easiest way to accomplish this without a doubt. Just click the more info button below.
  </p>
    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more_info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <span title="Click for more info">more info</span></div>
    <div id="more_info" class="collapse">Some hidden infomration you ony want to be seen when the user click on the control link.</div>
</div>
```

or add three divs floating perfectly without all the css, each with drop downs more info.

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>
            Honestly, Bootstrap would be the easiest way to accomplish this without a doubt. Just click the more info button below.
        </p>
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more_info">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <span title="Click for more info">more info</span>                                                                                </div>
        <div id="more_info" class="collapse">
            Some hidden information you only want to be seen when the user click on the control link.
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>
        Some other information we want to have a hidden drop down with more info for.
    </p>
    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more_info2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
        <span title="Click for more info">more info</span>
    </div>
    <div id="more_info2" class="collapse">
        Some hidden information you only want to be seen when the user click on the control link.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>
            Yet another div with info that has a drop down menu for more info included below. 
        </p>
    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more_info3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
        <span title="Click for more info">more info</span>     
    </div>
    <div id="more_info3" class="collapse">
        Some hidden infomration you ony want to be seen when the user click on the control link.
    </div>
</div>
```

Best of luck.